# Legacy Auto-Update, Needs Attention

Tags: composer-php, packagist

When I log into packagist.org I get this message on my packages:

> This package is using the legacy GitHub service and will stop being auto-updated in early 2019. Please set up the new [GitHub Hook](https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages) for Packagist so that it keeps working in the future.

When I visit https://packagist.org/about#how-to-update-packages the instructions seem to be more talking about how to set it up from scratch then anything.

- I'm already logged in and my GitHub account is already linked (do I need to unlink it and relink it?)
- When I click on https://github.com/settings/connections/applications/a059f127e1c09c04aa5a I see the "Access public information (read-only)" has a green checkbox next to it.
- When I check https://packagist.org/profile/ it doesn't say that they're not automatically sync'd. What it does say is "Legacy Auto-Update, Needs Attention".
- The URL suggests you trigger a manual account sync "to have Packagist try to set up hooks on your account again". I'm assuming the way you make Packagist do a manual sync is by clicking the "Update" button. I tried that to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at this issue: https://github.com/composer/packagist/issues/907 - GitHub deprecated GitHub Services, which was previously used for integration with Packagist. Packagist should switch to GitHub app when you first login to Packagist using GitHub OAuth.

If you already have connected GitHub account to Packagist account, try to logout and login using GitHub - you will be asked about permissions, which allows to automatically setup webhooks for repositories. After this everything should update automatically.
In other case you can connect GitHub account to existing Packagist account on [settings page](https://packagist.org/profile/edit).

Comment: This had me stumped too, running around in circles. The solution is to disconnect packagist from github then reconnect again, as stated. Everything kind of updates from there in a few seconds. Packagist really needs a button to manually perform this sync.